# Erro em classes que implementam java.io.Serializable

Tags: java

Tenho algumas classes que implementam java.io.Serializable, quando vou compilar, todas apresentam a warning:

> The serializable class Fat_uc_dataStatementSql does not declare a
>   static final serialVersionUID field of type long

O que pode estar ocorrendo? O que é essa constante que ele pede?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em runtime cada classe serializable tem um número de versão(serialVersionUID),  na desserialização o objeto é verificado, se a versão do objeto não for compatível com a versão do objeto de quem requisitou uma InvalidClassException ira ocorrer, portanto quando você declara uma classe serializável é conveniente declarar uma serialVersionUID explicitamente que deve ser static, final, e do tipo long. Mas se você não deixar explícito um serialVersionUID default sera criado em tempo de execução, portanto não se torna obrigatório embora você devesse considerar fazer, por isso é apenas um warning e não um erro, abraços.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade isso é só um warning (uma adivertência). o que pode inclusive ser desabilitada com ***@SuppressWarnings("serial")***

```
import ...
.
.
.
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AplicacaoEntity implements Serializable {  
    private Long id;
    private String descricao;
.
.
.
```

ou acrescentando na classe a linha :
*private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;* conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
import ...
.
.
.
public class AplicacaoEntity implements Serializable {  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String descricao;
.
.
.
```

**Importante:**
*se você estiver montando um projeto JSF, lembre-se que todo bean com escopo session é obrigatória que implemente o serializable;*

Espero ter ajudado;